# Find out when my repo clone was last merged(pushed) into origin

Tags: git

I have a git repository clone locally on my machine that I've been working with for a few weeks and already merged my work once into the main repo("origin").
I can find my last merge(of course) in origin's log but I'm wondering if there is the "right"(and automated) way to do it - to find out when was the last time this clone was pushed to origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the common ancestor of your local branch and the origin branch. This can be done using `git merge-base`:

```
git merge-base master origin/master
```

Which returns a commit hash.

**Why it works**: if you use a good git workflow, you will need to update your local branch with the latest remote changes (either with `merge` or `rebase`) before pushing. After this, your local branch will point to a commit containing your work and pushing to a remote just means to make the remote branch point to your commit.

As a result, the remote repository will always contain the commit which was your head when you pushed.

However, this won't work if someone else (or you, from another head) forces a push (`git push -f`) and erases your commit. Forcing a push on a shared repository should be avoided except in some rare cases.

Comment: This is my *local branch commit* hash that was merged to the origin branch?

Comment: seems like local commit and commit(result of `push`) on origin - have the same hash. cool!

Comment: @kerim I've updated the answer with a short paragraph explaining why it works (in most cases)